# A proof of total sum of squares being equal to within-cluster sum of squares and between cluster sum of squares?

Tags: clustering, sums-of-squares

In cluster analysis I have frequently encountered a statement that the total sum of squares  $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{{({x_i} - \overline x )}^2}} $ being equal to within-cluster sum of squares $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^K {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{{n_k}} {{z_{ik}}{{({x_i} - {{\overline x }_k})}^2}} } $ and between cluster sum of squares $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^K {\frac{{{n_k}}}{n}{{({{\overline x }_k} - \overline x )}^2}} $, where $n$ is the total number of elements, $K$ is the number of clusters, $n_k$ is the number of elements in the $k$th cluster, ${{{\overline x }_k}}$ is the mean of the $k$th cluster, $z_{ik}$ is an indicator function ${z_{ik}} = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&{{x_i} \in {\rm{cluster }}k}\\
0&{{x_i} \notin {\rm{cluster }}k}
\end{array}} \right.$. Anyone can provide a proof that the following equation indeed holds?

> $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{{({x_i} - \overline x )}^2}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^K {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{{n_k}} {{z_{ik}}{{({x_i} - {{\overline x }_k})}^2}} }  + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^K {{{{n_k}}}{{({{\overline x }_k} - \overline x )}^2}} $

Thank you!

Comment: The factor $n_k/n$ in the second term should probably be $n_k$.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. You are right. I have edited the question.

Comment: To those who marked this question as duplicate. I don't think my question duplicates "Partitioning sum of squares".

Comment: Can you explain why? It would help if you edited your question to state what you understand from the other Q & what you still need to know. Then you might get the answers you need, rather than just material that already didn't help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to see this would be to use the [law of total variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance),
$$\text{Var}[X] = \text{E}[\text{Var}[X \mid K]] + \text{Var}[\text{E}[X \mid K]],$$
applied to the distributions
\begin{align}
p(x \mid k) &= \sum_i \frac{z_{ik}}{n_k} \delta(x - x_i), & p(k) &= \frac{n_k}{n}.
\end{align}

The more direct proof is straightforward but lengthy, which is probably why it wasn't mentioned in your books. Using the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) and
\begin{align}
\sum_i z_{ik} &= n_k, & \sum_k z_{ik} &= 1,
\end{align}
it follows that
\begin{align}
\sum_i (x_i - \bar x)^2
&= \sum_i \sum_k z_{ik} (x_i - \bar x)^2 \\
&= \sum_i \sum_k z_{ik} (x_i - \bar x_k + \bar x_k - \bar x)^2 \\
&= \sum_k \sum_i z_{ik} \left( (x_i - \bar x_k)^2 + 2 (x_i - \bar x_k) (\bar x_k - \bar x) + (\bar x_k - \bar x)^2 \right) \\
&= \sum_k \sum_i z_{ik} (x_i - \bar x_k)^2 + 2 \sum_k \sum_i z_{ik} (x_i - \bar x_k) (\bar x_k - \bar x) + \sum_k \sum_i z_{ik} (\bar x_k - \bar x)^2 \\
&= \sum_k \sum_i z_{ik} (x_i - \bar x_k)^2 + 2 \sum_k  (\bar x_k - \bar x) \left( \sum_i z_{ik} x_i - \sum_i z_{ik} \bar x_k \right) + \sum_k n_k (\bar x_k - \bar x)^2 \\
&= \sum_k \sum_i z_{ik} (x_i - \bar x_k)^2 + 2 \sum_k  (\bar x_k - \bar x) \left( n_k \bar x_k - n_k \bar x_k \right) + \sum_k n_k (\bar x_k - \bar x)^2 \\
&= \sum_k \sum_i z_{ik} (x_i - \bar x_k)^2 + \sum_k n_k (\bar x_k - \bar x)^2.
\end{align}